# Replacing the date in a csv file with mm-yyyy

Tags: date, sed, replace

I have a csv file consisting of one column of dates. The date format is dd.mm.yyyy. How can I use sed to replace the date with the mm-yy format? That is, to replace the date with mm-yyyy, which is a text and dropping the day in the date. An example of the input csv file is:

```
11.12.2018
21.01.2019
07.02.2019
29.03.2019
01.04.2019
```

I would like the output to be:

```
12-18
01-19
02-19
03-19
04-19
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -r 's/...(..)...(..)/\1-\2/' file
```

> `-r`: use extended regular expressions in the script.

Output:

```
12-18
01-19
02-19
03-19
04-19
```

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: I get the following error message: sed: illegal option -- r
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]

Comment: You don't use GNU sed. Try to replace `-r` with `-E`.